# PHP/MySql changing format of array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have this array named $myArray:

```
Array ( 
[0] => bb 
[1] => kk
[2] => ll )
```

On which I´m querying with:

```
$sql = ("SELECT username FROM Users WHERE username IN ('" .   implode("','",$myArray) . "')   AND status > 0 ");
$result = $conn->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r ($result);
```

What I get is:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [username] => bb ) 
[1] => Array ( [username] => kk ) )
```

But what I want to get is:

```
Array ( 
[0] => bb 
[1] => kk ) )
```

What can I do to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: remove again using the username after WHERE

Comment: `$new_array = array_values($result);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The printed array is in the format in which it should be.

This is because that you may select more than one column in an SQL query, so that each row should be an array.

What you can do is simply traverse the array again and re-format the array to the shape you want.

```
foreach ($result as &$value){
    $value = $value['username'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
$query =  $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM Users WHERE username IN ('" .   implode("','",$myArray) . "')   AND status > 0 ");
$query->execute();
$myArray = array();
if($query->rowCount() > 0){
    $i = 0;
    while($data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($data);echo"</pre>";
        $myArray[$i] = $data;
        $i++;
    }
}
print_r($myArray);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a 1 liner:

```
$result = array_column($result,"username");
```